# How to restrict highlighting an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I have an embedded mobile game that is wrapped in an iframe, and the game requires users to hold their finger down to make the player fly.

`<iframe style= "position:relative;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;border:0;" src="https://play.gamepix.com/badland/embed" allowFullScreen></iframe>`

The game works great, but when you hold your finger down, the entire screen is highlighted with a transparent blue color and the “copy/share” icon pops up in the middle of the game. I have tried adding:

```
-webkit-user-select: none;
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
```

…but it doesn’t work.

Is there a way to restrict highlighting/selecting an iframe?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `frameborder=0`?

```
<iframe frameborder="0" style="background:none transparent;position:relative;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;border:0;" src="https://play.gamepix.com/badland/embed" allowFullScreen>
</iframe>
```

If you're not looking for it then, please provide some screenshots for better understanding.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately it didn’t work. I added a screenshot.